# Why I have "model." in front of every key name of the state dict?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, resnet, pytorch-lightning

I have trained my ResNet50 model with Pytorch Lightning framework. Everything was same as usual. After getting my .pth file (which is state dict file for my model), when I loaded the file back and tried to test the model, I got this error. It seens that every keys in the state_dict had "model." added above each key name. Is there any way to fundamentally fix this instead of just replacing keys in the .pth file?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c321e72c89af> in <module>()
      1 model = ResNet50()
----> 2 model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
      3 model.eval()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
   1481         if len(error_msgs) > 0:
   1482             raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
-> 1483                                self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   1484         return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)
   1485 

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ResNet:
    Missing key(s) in state_dict: "conv1.weight", "bn1.weight", "bn1.bias", "bn1.running_mean", "bn1.running_var", "layer1.0.conv1.weight", "layer1.0.bn1.weight", "layer1.0.bn1.bias", "layer1.0.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn1.running_var", "layer1.0.conv2.weight", "layer1.0.bn2.weight", "layer1.0.bn2.bias", "layer1.0.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn2.running_var", "layer1.0.conv3.weight", "layer1.0.bn3.weight", "layer1.0.bn3.bias", "layer1.0.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.0.bn3.running_var", "layer1.0.shortcut.0.weight", "layer1.0.shortcut.1.weight", "layer1.0.shortcut.1.bias", "layer1.0.shortcut.1.running_mean", "layer1.0.shortcut.1.running_var", "layer1.1.conv1.weight", "layer1.1.bn1.weight", "layer1.1.bn1.bias", "layer1.1.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn1.running_var", "layer1.1.conv2.weight", "layer1.1.bn2.weight", "layer1.1.bn2.bias", "layer1.1.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn2.running_var", "layer1.1.conv3.weight", "layer1.1.bn3.weight", "layer1.1.bn3.bias", "layer1.1.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.1.bn3.running_var", "layer1.2.conv1.weight", "layer1.2.bn1.weight", "layer1.2.bn1.bias", "layer1.2.bn1.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn1.running_var", "layer1.2.conv2.weight", "layer1.2.bn2.weight", "layer1.2.bn2.bias", "layer1.2.bn2.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn2.running_var", "layer1.2.conv3.weight", "layer1.2.bn3.weight", "layer1.2.bn3.bias", "layer1.2.bn3.running_mean", "layer1.2.bn3.running_var", "layer2.0.conv1.weight", "layer2.0.bn1.weight", "layer2.0.bn1.bias", "layer2.0.bn1.running_m...
    Unexpected key(s) in state_dict: "model.conv1.weight", "model.bn1.weight", "model.bn1.bias", "model.bn1.running_mean", "model.bn1.running_var", "model.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "model.layer1.0.conv1.weight", "model.layer1.0.bn1.weight", "model.layer1.0.bn1.bias", "model.layer1.0.bn1.running_mean", "model.layer1.0.bn1.running_var", "model.layer1.0.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "model.layer1.0.conv2.weight", "model.layer1.0.bn2.weight", "model.layer1.0.bn2.bias", "model.layer1.0.bn2.running_mean", "model.layer1.0.bn2.running_var", "model.layer1.0.bn2.num_batches_tracked", "model.layer1.0.conv3.weight", "model.layer1.0.bn3.weight", "model.layer1.0.bn3.bias", "model.layer1.0.bn3.running_mean", "model.layer1.0.bn3.running_var", "model.layer1.0.bn3.num_batches_tracked", "model.layer1.0.shortcut.0.weight", "model.layer1.0.shortcut.1.weight", "model.layer1.0.shortcut.1.bias", "model.layer1.0.shortcut.1.running_mean", "model.layer1.0.shortcut.1.running_var", "model.layer1.0.shortcut.1.num_batches_tracked", "model.layer1.1.conv1.weight", "model.layer1.1.bn1.weight", "model.layer1.1.bn1.bias", "model.layer1.1.bn1.running_mean", "model.layer1.1.bn1.running_var", "model.layer1.1.bn1.num_batches_tracked", "model.layer1.1.conv2.weight", "model.layer1.1.bn2.weight", "model.layer1.1.bn2.bias", "model.layer1.1.bn2.running_mean", "model.layer1.1.bn2.running_var", "model.layer1.1.bn2.num_batches_tracked", "model.layer1.1.conv3.weight", "model.layer1.1.bn3.weight", "model.layer1.1.bn3.bias", "mod...
```

Comment: Please include the code you use to save the model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initiate your model in the same manner as done during training.

For example, `model= torchvision.models.resnet50()` for training.You have to initialize the model in same manner.